# Identificar/Autenticar cliente num websocket

Tags: php, javascript, socket, websocket

Estou a criar um simples servidor de *sockets* em *PHP*, mas estou com algumas duvidas, visto que é a primeira vez que faço algo do gênero. A minha duvida é como é que eu identifico o cliente, isto é, através de um sistema de autenticação, talvez.

O que eu tentei até agora:

- Cookies
- Hash

Código Servidor: https://www.codepile.net/pile/vBZP9xkq

Código Cliente: https://www.codepile.net/pile/YlD2JDjB

---

#### Cookies

Eu quando comecei a criar o servidor, pensei que nenhum sistema de autenticação fosse necessário, visto que eu tenho o site com *login*. Em principio, o *socket* iria partilhar o mesmo *cookie* e, dessa forma, no servidor de *sockets*, eu teria acesso à sessão do cliente.

Assim saberia que o *socket X* seria do *cliente X*.

Mas, para minha surpresa, nos *headers* vem um *phpsessid* diferente e como são diferentes, não funciona.

```
PHPSESSID=7fo97nhaqfgir55ar17cr8c364 // No *PHP* e *JavaScript* (site)
PHPSESSID=isjbjik06p0d8srm4j1ccptj2b // No socket
```

#### Hash

Foi a minha segunda abordagem, adicionei parâmetros ao endereço do *socket*:

- meusocket.pt:9000/?h=123456789

Mas depressa me apercebi que no servidor de *sockets* não conseguia apanhar nada, os *headers* e variável `$_SERVER` e `$_REQUEST` não levam os parâmetros.

Mais tarde entendi que não passa visto que não é um pedido de http, por isso não transporta essa informação.

---

#### Conclusão

Neste momento estou um pouco perdido, não sei como identificar o cliente que entra no *socket*, sendo que a única informação que tenho é o *IP* e isto é inviável visto que no mesmo *IP* pode ter *X* clientes.

Alguém me consegue explicar a forma correcta de se fazer a autenticação num *socket*?

Comment: Talvez ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4361173/9101590

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Já tinha passado por ai, alias criei este tópico porque não vejo uma forma "plug and play". Nessa caso eles falam de usar um sub protocolo, mas olhando assim de fora não me parece a forma correta de ser feito, usando um custom protocol com o hash. Não há ninguém que explique lá o porque de usar essa técnica, o que me deixa um pouco de pé atrás em usar essa solução.

Answer (score 1):

Tenho que me aventurar em sockets com php, só trabalhei com java. Mas acredito que no momento que é feito o acesso ao socket tu pode criar uma thread para cada client, pode ter ate um array com todas as threads.
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.thread.php.

Comment: Isso seria bom para a gestão dos clientes do servidor de sockets, ainda assim mantinha o mesmo problema, relacionar o cliente que entra no socket com os clientes que tenho no site (base de dados). Visto que a única coisa que eu tenho comum é o ip.